# What is the reason for explicitly converting an int within String.Format()

Tags: c#

In most code that I come across, they explicitly convert an int or other number to a string while using String.Format(), although from what I've noticed it is not necessary. Is there something I'm missing which requires explicit conversion of a number to a string before using it as a string?

**Explicit:**

```
int i = 13;
string example = String.Format("If a Friday lands on the {0}th of the month, it is generally considered to be an unlucky day!",
                               i.ToString());
```

Which produces `example` as: `"If a Friday lands on the 13th of the month, it is generally considered to be an unlucky day!"`

**Non-explicit:**

```
int i = 13;
string example = String.Format("If a Friday lands on the {0}th of the month, it is generally considered to be an unlucky day!",
                                i);
```

Which produces `example` as: `"If a Friday lands on the 13th of the month, it is generally considered to be an unlucky day!"` (the same as explicitly converting). So why do the majority of coders I see do this?

Comment: You've got it backwards.  Calling `ToString()` is *explicitly* converting `i` to a string.  Passing `i` directly to `Format()` means that the conversion happens *implicitly*.

Comment: Where have you been looking? It's highly unusual to see calls to `ToString()` being applied to arguments to `String.Format()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use an implicit conversion, the `int` is boxed to `object` first. That's a *tiny* performance hit, but one which some people seem to think is important, and may explain the code.

Indeed, Jeffrey Richter wrote about this (encouraging the use of this sort of thing) in his otherwise-excellent CLR via C#. It irritated me enough that I [blogged about it](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/10/08/why-boxing-doesn-t-keep-me-awake-at-nights.aspx) :)

Of course in *some* places, boxing may be relevant - but given that `string.Format` needs to walk the format string and do all kinds of other things, I wouldn't expect it to be significant here... and that's before you consider what you're going to do with the string next :)

Comment: At the cost of forfeiting the ability to specify numeric formatting within the `String.Format` argument, too. (e.g. `{0:C}` within the format string now becomes `i.ToString("C")` within the argument list).

Comment: @BradChristie: Absolutely. It's crazy in various ways. Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't see a reason to do this. Since `String.Format()` does this already, as you point out, it is more compact and IMO easier to read if you just let `String.Format()` take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

Because we are used to the rules and you'd better be too. `String.Format()` is a clever method, every method is not. remember that `String.Format()` takes objects so you don't need to convert, however if you do you are still sending an object.